# How are "Days" determined for Warframe login rewards?

Tags: warframe

If I log in at 11pm and 1am (EST) I do not get the log in reward twice for logging in 2 consecutive days.  In fact, even at 10pm and 2am.

I am curious what the requirements are between getting the log in rewards 2 days in a row. Does there need to be a certain amount of time in between the log ins or is it just based on a different timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reset time for [Daily Rewards](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Login_Rewards) is at Midnight, Greenwich Mean Time. Which would be at 7:00PM EST.